# Is a kernel just a symmetric, positive semi-definite, and continuous matrix?

Tags: reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

From page 9 of [these](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-097-prediction-machine-learning-and-statistics-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT15_097S12_lec13.pdf) course notes,

> A function $k : \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is  a *kernel* if
>
> - $k$ is symmetric: $k(x,y) = k(y,x)$
> - $k$ gives rise to a positive semi-definite "Gram matrix," i.e., for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and any $x_1,\dots,x_m$ chosen from $\mathcal{X}$, the Gram matrix $\mathbf{K}$ defined by $K_{ij} = k(x_i,x_j)$ is positive semi-definite.

From this definition, it seems that a kernel can be thought of as a "continuous" matrix $\mathbf{A}$ that consists of infinitely many rows and columns, where $k(x,y)$ is one element of $\mathbf{A}$. Additionally, $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite. Furthermore, in page 14 of the same course notes, the author writes

> #### Mercer's Theorem
>
> The inspiration of the name "kernel" comes from the study of integral operators, studied by Hilbert and others. Function $k$ which gives rise to an operator $T_k$ via:
> $$
> (T_k f)(x) = \int_\mathcal{X} k(x,x') f(x') \ \text{d}x'
> $$
> is called the *kernel* of $T_k$.

The expression for $(T_k f)(x)$ looks like an infinite matrix-vector product, where the infinitely many columns of $\mathbf{A}$ are linearly combined using the elements of the vector $f$.

Is this way of thinking about a kernel correct?